# Implementing recursive ajax call and stop it at one condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have been searching and trying for hours, but as a newbie in ajax things, I have been failing to get what I want. Here is the thing: 
1. I have a page which fetches current date's data from the db, so I am calling ajax function recursively with `setTimeOut()` of some `10 seconds` to show the updated db recrods.
2. Here I am failing. I have date picker, so as soon as the user selects the past date from jquery picker, I should stop the current ajax process and fetch that particular date's data and I don't want this to call recursively because the past data never gets changed.

**Code for the recursive thing**

```
function makeCall(selectedDate) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divtable").hide();
    $.get('getdataservlet',{ 'selectedDate': selectedDate },function(responseJson) {
      if (responseJson!=null) {
        $("#datatable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var table1 = $("#datatable");
        $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
          var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
          rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['first']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['two']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['three']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['four']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['five']); 
          rowNew.appendTo(table1);
        });
      }
      setTimeout(makeCall, 10000,selectedDate);
    });
    $("#divtable").show();
  });
}

makeCall(currentDate());
```

For the first time the `makeCall(currentDate())` would be called and it continues recursing with `setTimeout()` for every 10 seconds.

**Code for Jquery Calendar**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dateinput").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
    // Here I want to make single ajax call while
    // stopping the current recursive call.
    // The recursive should continue again when user selects current date.
    },
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

Can someone please help me on this? Sorry I am unable to format the code in the question properly despite of trying it many times.

Comment: Whats error that u are geting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a boolean flag to indicate is the currentDate selected:

```
var someFlag = true,
    timeout = null;
function makeCall(selectedDate) {
  if (someFlag == true) {
    $("#divtable").hide();
    $.get('getdataservlet',{ 'selectedDate': selectedDate },function(responseJson) {
      if ((!isCurrentDate(selected) || someFlag == true) && responseJson!=null) {
        $("#datatable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var table1 = $("#datatable");
        $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
          var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
          rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['first']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['two']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['three']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['four']); 
          rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['five']); 
          rowNew.appendTo(table1);
        });
      }
      timeout = setTimeout(makeCall, 10000, selectedDate);
    });
    $("#divtable").show();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  makeCall(currentDate());
});
```

Also implement function isCurrentDate that returns boolean value if provided date is currentDate.

```
$(function() {
  $("#dateinput").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
       clearTimeout(timeout);
       if (isCurrentDate(date)) {
           someFlag = true;
           makeCall(date);
       } else {
           someFlag = false;
       }
    },
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this stops the current call, but I want to call the same functionality for once when the user selects other date. And also I should cancel the current running call when he changes date i.e., in the else condition of your second code snippet

Comment: See `onSelect` callback - my code checking is the currentDate selected. And I modified if statement in ajax callback. And clearTimeout to prevent execution of ajax callback. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a call to the makecall function again in the else and keeping if (someFlag == true) only for  timeout = setTimeout(makeCall, 10000, selectedDate);

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `clearTimeout` on the timer if the selected date is less than today's date

```
var timer;
function makeCall(selectedDate) {
  $.get(...
  ....
  if (selectedDate < new Date() && timer) {
    // If a timer is already running and the selected date is less than today, stop it
    clearTimeout(timer);  
  } else {
    // Start a timer
    timer = setTimeout(makeCall, 10000, selectedDate);
  }
```

and call this function in document.ready and when a new date is selected

Simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5762/) to demonstrate usage (enter a number in the text box to stop the loop)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to show the data once even when he selects the other date except current date(without recursion). In the example it just clears the timer in the else condition

Comment: In that case, move the `$get() method and associated code to before the `if` statement (I'll update answer in a moment)